# First chance exception of type System.NullReference exception in PresentationFramework.dll?

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics

I am having trouble figuring out an exception that occurs in my application.

Basically, I am hosting a wpf user control which has an infragistics XamDataGrid in it.

When I close the application, I am getting an infinite loop of exceptions of type:

The thread '' (0x24020) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
and so on....

If I REMOVE THE XAMDATAGRID, everything works fine...so im guessing its an issue with the grid...

A part of the stack trace is: (Im not sure if this is helpful:)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DeferredAppResourceReference.GetValue(System.Windows.BaseValueSourceInternal valueSource = Inherited) + 0x4d bytes

WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetEffectiveValue(System.Windows.EntryIndex entryIndex = {System.Windows.EntryIndex}, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp = {System.Windows.DependencyProperty}, System.Windows.RequestFlags requests) + 0xe6 bytes

WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetValueEntry(System.Windows.EntryIndex entryIndex, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp = {System.Windows.DependencyProperty}, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata metadata = {System.Windows.FrameworkPropertyMetadata}, System.Windows.RequestFlags requests = FullyResolved) + 0x2fe bytes

WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp) + 0x48 bytes 
    PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Text.TextProperties.InitCommon(System.Windows.DependencyObject target = {System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock}) + 0x6b bytes 
    PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Text.TextProperties.TextProperties(System.Windows.FrameworkElement target = {System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock}, bool isTypographyDefaultValue = true) + 0x42 bytes
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.GetLineProperties() + 0x37 bytes
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.EnsureTextBlockCache() + 0x2f bytes 
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size constraint) + 0x50 bytes
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size availableSize) + 0x1ee bytes
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size availableSize) + 0x249 bytes
    PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(System.Windows.UIElement element, System.Windows.Size constraint) + 0xfe bytes
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size constraint) + 0x18 bytes 
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size availableSize) + 0x1ee bytes
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size availableSize) + 0x249 bytes
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size constraint) + 0x10c bytes 
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size availableSize) + 0x1ee bytes
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size availableSize) + 0x249 bytes
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size constraint) + 0x187 bytes
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size availableSize) + 0x1ee bytes
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size availableSize) + 0x249 bytes
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size constraint) + 0x1cf bytes

---

Any help on how to go about solving this is really appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: How about putting the code where you instantiate the Grid that you are using.. also did you add a reference at the project level.. besides the using... ??

Comment: hi, Im a newbie to wpf so i apologize if im not being clear....its just a simple XamDataGrid...I instantiate it as Xamdatagrid grid = new Xamdatagrid(); grid.Datasource = mysource; and then I add it to a StackPanel as sp.Children.Add(grid). Does that answer yur question? Thanks!

Comment: Can we see some code then.. it may just help

Comment: ok...I will try to put something together.

Comment: Cool.. I am sure other helpers on StackOverFlow would like to see what you are doing ..especially in the Initialize portion thanks

Comment: Why do you care about first-chance exceptions? These are exceptions that will be handled.

Comment: is there an Exception Message to go with the stack trace?

Comment: The excpetion message is : "Object Reference not set to an istance of an Object"

Comment: @ John Saunders...because the application crashes.

Comment: Looking at the stack trace I don't see any Infragistics methods in the stack trace.  You mentioned that the issue doesn't happen if you remove the XamDataGrid.  When you do this do you remove it from the user control or do you remove the user control containing the XamDataGrid?  Also does the behavior change if you use a container that has a height or width set such as a Grid in place of the StackPanel?

Comment: hi alhalma...when i remove it i remove the user control containing the grid...I didnt try it by setting it on a grid rather than a StackPanel...do you think that will make a differencce?

Comment: I just tessted it with a set grid.,,same thing happens...

Comment: If you press Ctrl + Alt + E in Visual Studio, it opens the Exceptions window. If you then check the checkbox that corresponds to `Thrown Common Language Runtime Exceptions', click OK and then run your application, when it crashes next, Visual Studio will show you where the problem is.

Comment: @ user1202434 What else is on the UserControl?  If you remove the XamDataGrid from the UserControl and still use the user control do you see the same behavior.  Does the application have to be in any specific state when closing the application for the first chance exception or does it happen every time?

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because when the winforms application shuts down, the WPF dispatcher thread has not finished flushing it pending queue for event messages. When it gets around to doing so, the application object has already been closed and nulled out. To resolve, right before the hosting window is closed, just invoke shutdown on the WPF message loop.

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown()
```

Comment: Thanks @outro56. That really saved my time. Great :)